# Cannot access network PC

Tags: networking, windows-7

I was able to access network PCs by entering \ComputerName in windows explorer. This was working before until I tried it again a while ago (not sure when it stopped working). The error message is:

"Windows cannot access \ComputerName check the spelling of the name, Otherwise, there might be a problem with your network. To try to identify and resolve network problems, click Diagnose."

When I click Diagnose, it says it cannot identify the problem. But other PCs on the network can still access this computer.

Here are the things I tried:

1. Accessing itself using its own computer name (\MyComputerName)
2. Using ip address instead of computer name
3. Checked that the network adapter's driver is up to date
4. Enabling and disabling network discovery
5. Pinging the computer name and ip address (its own or other PCs) works fine
6. I was able to access the router's console using internet browser. (`http://192.168.254.1`)
7. I was able to view another PC running IIS using internet browser using both computer name (`http://OtherPc`) and ip address (`192.168.254.100`)
8. Disabled firewall (windows firewall, no 3rd party firewall installed). Disabled virusscan.

P.S.
    Internet connection is working fine.
    The computer is running on windows 7

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this connection?

Comment: And this has absolutely nothing to do with programming, which is what SO is meant for. There's a help button at the top of every screen which should assist you in targeting the right site for your question.

Comment: trueamerican420, it is used for file sharing

Comment: Have you tried `ping`ing the IP address of `MyComputerName`?

Comment: Tried connecting through the "Run" Dialogue box?

Comment: rink.attendant.6: ping works on both computer names and ip addresses (its own or other PCs).

Comment: Scandalist: Same error using Run

Answer (score 0):

> Old: You should use 2 slashes in Explorer when looking up the computer
>   name.

You should check the network connection type in windows 7. Enter this in explorer:

```
Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center
```

Under your connection you are trying to use to access the PC, check under the name. If it is public network, you will need to change it to work or home.

Comment: Sorry, that is a type. I did use 2 slashes

Comment: Just updated with another thing you can try.

Comment: It is set to Work Network. Also, other PCs are able to access this computer.

Comment: Hmm. Only other thing I'd think to check is if the remote PC can connect to yours using the same process.

Comment: Yes. Other PCs can connect to that PC using both computer name and ip address.

Comment: I meant to ask, can the trouble PC connect to your PC.

Comment: No. The trouble PC can't connect to anything using explorer. But I was able to connect to my PC (which is hosting a web site (for tests) using IIS) using an internet browser.

Comment: Update: I also tried using \\localhost, which works on other PCs even when disconnected to the network, but this also fails on the trouble PC.

Answer (score 0):

On the computer you want to connect make sure that in Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings page that Network discovery and file/printer sharing is turned on for the profile its on (Its possible something in your network changed and now you're set to a public network). This will turn on the services and open the ports. The computer connecting to it doesn't need these enabled, it just needs to be able to see the computer. (Which is can, because you said you can ping it)

Comment: Both network discovery, file and printer sharing are turned on.